# React native state not updated inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am calling one of my component methods after updating its state. The problem I am experiencing is that, inside that method, the state is not updated.

This is my current code:

```
const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    ...

    const fetchData = async () => {
         ...
         const { data: newData } = await api.fetchData(...);
         ...
         setData([...data, ...newData]) // <--- Here, data is not updated, after having called handleOnSelectFilter()
         ...
    }

    const handleOnSelectFilter = (filter) => {
        // Reset data before fetching api
        setData([]);

        ...

        // Fetch data
        fetchData();
    }


    ...
}
```

As you can see, this is happening because the "fetchData" instance which is called inside handleOnSelectFilter hasn't be redefined yet due to the React asynchronous state updates.

How can I solve my problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Setting state in react is async. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function But you can send a function to setDate function, which takes the current state as the first argument: replace with `setData((current) => [...current, ...newData])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if perhaps the first setData, which resets `data` to an empty array, might be the one that you're thinking isn't working? It's a little unclear. If that's correct, this is a common problem and can easily be fixed with an arrow function in the setData (see [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)):

```
setData([]);
setData(d=> [...d, ...newData]);
```

After the first `setData`, the `data` variable will be stale until the next time the functional component is refreshed. But with the arrow function/functional update, you will get the current value that you just set.